# Why is my plotly graph plotting datetime on x axis as exponents?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, plotly

I am trying to plot a graph with dates (pandas datetime) on the x axis. However, they are plotting in numerical format instead (showing up as exponents).

Example of dates:

```
0   2014-05-01
1   2014-05-02
2   2014-05-03
3   2014-05-04
4   2014-05-05
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Code for plotly:

```
trace1 = go.Scatter(x = df_iso_h.date, 
                y=del18_f_hum,
               mode = 'markers')
data = [trace1]
py.iplot(data)
```

My x-axis:
[image]

Not sure how to fix this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `layout` and specify parameter `xaxis` in it. Such as [here](https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/#style-scatter-plots).

So try this:

```
# Create trace
trace1 = go.Scatter(x = df_iso_h.date, 
                y=del18_f_hum,
               mode = 'markers')
# Add trace in data
data = [trace1]
# Create layout. With layout you can customize plotly plot
layout = dict(title = 'Scatter',
              # Add what you want to see at xaxis
              xaxis = df_iso_h.date
             )
#Do not forget added layout to fig!
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
# Plot scatter
py.iplot(data, filename="scatterplot")
```

This should help you.

Update: Try to convert `datetime` column with `strftime` (new column should be in `object` format!):

```
df_iso_h["date"] = df_iso_h["date"].dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

If not worked, add this column in `xaxis`. Maybe `plotly` do not support datetime format `yyyy-mm-dd`... Notice, you `xaxis` will be looks like `01-05-2014`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not prevent plotly from converting the datetime to numerical format. I cannot figure out why it is displaying my x-axis numerically instead of as a date format like yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out... Plotly does not take pandas datetime, so I had to convert my pandas datetime to python datetime.datetime or datetime.date.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this was a regression introduced in plotly.py Version 3.2.0 and has been fixed in Version 3.2.1

You can now simply pass the pandas datetime column to plotly and it will handle the proper conversion for you like in the past.

See https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1160